# Fullpage.js Sliding options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have an animation that id like to trigger with the trigger of the parallax efect of fullpage.js

Id like to execute this everytime it fullpage.js switches sections.

The Code Css i want to be executed:

```
.mask-white{
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 22222;
 animation: height-white 1s;
 }

@keyframes height-white {

 0%{
    height: 0vh;
    bottom: 0;
   }
 50%{
    height: 100vh;
    }
 100%{
    height: 0vh;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

I want it to be executed 1 everytime onleave is called.

```
... fullpage.js code is above ...

 onLeave: function(){

 }
```

This function is called everytime the section is switched, which is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the class `mask-white` on the element you wish on your `onLeave` callback.

See an example of how to deal with callbacks or css3 animations based on fullpage.js state classes on my video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M